# Angular js - Not able to regenerate the view over ng-view on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to Angualr Js, I am trying to implement a simple app, Below is my requirement,

1. My application has three roles, basing on the roles i am rendering different pages.
2. In the role based rendered page, i have few links, on click of each link, i am rendering few more features.

Initially i am using ng-include to render my view by calling a method in my controller which hits the service and get the role and basing on the role, i am returning the view.

### **Home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" data-ng-app="vendorPortalApp" data-ng-controller="vendorPortalController">
        <div data-ng-include="getView()">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am intializing the angular services and controller along with routes here 
**app.js**

```
angular.module('vendorPortalApp', ['vendorPortalApp.controllers','vendorPortalApp.services','ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/home", {controller: "vendorPortalController"}).
    when("/home/resetPassword", {templateUrl: "features/resetPassword.html",           controller: "vendorResetPasswordController"}).
    when("/home/editProfile",{templateUrl: "features/editProfile.html",controller:"vendorEditProfileController"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});}]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('vendorPortalApp.controllers', []).controller('vendorPortalController', function($scope,serviceApi) {
$scope.role = null;
serviceApi.getUserSessionData().success(function (response) {
        $scope.role = response;
 });

$scope.getView = function() {
    if($scope.role == "SuperAdmin"){
        return "views/SuperAdmin.html";
    }else if($scope.role == "Admin"){
        return "views/Admin.html";
    }else if($scope.role == "User"){
        return "views/User.html";
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}}).controller('vendorResetPasswordController',function($scope,serviceApi){

}).controller('vendorEditProfileController',function($scope,serviceApi){

});
```

**views/SuperAdmin.html**

```html
<div class="left-content">
<a href="#/home/editProfile">Edit Profile</a>
<a href="#/home/resetPassword">Reset Password</a>
</div>
<div class="right-content">
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

I have a folder named features, in which i have editProfile.html, and resetPassword.html partial views, i wanted to get these partial views rendered on anchor click on SuperAdmin.html

**editProfile.html**

```html
<section data-ng-controller="vendorEditProfileController">
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>
Firstname : <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
Lastname : <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</section>
```

**ResetPassword.html**

```html
<section data-ng-controller="vendorResetPasswordController">
<h1> Reset Password </h1>
Password : <input type="password" name="reset-password">
Confirm Password : <input type="password" name="confirm password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</section>
```

I am able to render the views based on role, Once the SuperAdmin.html view got rendered, i have few anchor links on the page, on each anchor link it references to #/home/editProfile and #/home/resetPassword, these url pattern match in the route configuration and render the appropriate feature from the features folder.

The only issue i am facing is, Lets say i have clicked on reset password link, my url gets updated to http://locahost/vendorapp/home.html#/home/resetPassword
and i get the reset password feature rendered over my page, Now when i am reloading the page, it gives me an issue, it wipes away the resetPassword.html feature, and even when we click on reset password link, it does not generate the view. Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console after following a link and the page stops working?

Comment: No I dont see any errors, but one thing i have noticed, if i have reloaded url which is #/home/resetPassword, the reset password link does not do anything, but if i click on edit profile link, it seems to be generating the edit profile view, same thing i have replicated with respect to editprofile url reload